# Access MacZFS via network from XBMC

Tags: macos, networking, kodi, zfs

I have a ZFS RAID (zpool with three drives) hooked up to my Mac that I want to share in my LAN so that the XBMC client on my OUYA console hooked up to the television can read the drive and use it to stream my movies and television shows onto the television set.

I've searched around for a bit but so far haven't found anything that helped me with it. I know that when connecting to the Mac with SSH I can't just access the drive due to different formatting.

What do I have to do so that XBMC will be able to read it? How do I share it?

Comment: Not familiar at all with XBMC nor much familiarity with OSX, but have you considered sharing it over some protocol like NFS or SMB/CIFS? Also, what's an OUYA console? **Basically**, forget the fact that it's ZFS and just focus on sharing the contents of the file system or directories between the relevant systems, and you're likely to hit something useful.

Comment: I cannot understand why the filesystem should make any difference, hether to ssh or to SMB/CIFS-NFS. The ssh/Samba sessions are run by Mac, which should be able to read data off your disks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to know what OSX you are running on and what version of XBMC.
For sharing you need to enable **Windows Sharing**
To do so, you need to navigate to your system preferences and turn on system sharing on the left under services. Then just select "Options" and check "Share Files and Folders using SMB (Windows)
After that just set up the account that you want to share with and set up the folders and everything.

Now for the issue you might encounter:
Since OS X 10.7 SMB protocol 2.0 is used and there were compatability issues... Since XBMC v 12.1 this issue is solved. If you are still on v11, you will need to upgrade. Or go for SMBUp...

For SMBUp you can follow this link: http://eduo.info/apps/smbup

That should solve al your problems.

Scott

Comment: Hey, I'm using OS X Mavericks and XBMC V12 on my OUYA. I just tried adding a folder on the ZFS drive to the file sharing and SMB was already activated. Now...the OUYA can see my computer and can see another folder on my local harddrive that I shared but it can't see the folder I shared on the RAID. Is that the bug you mentioned because folders on the internal HD work fine :(